# Eclipse Junit run configuration that takes the current selected test class as an arg?

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

Instead of constantly creating identical debug configuraitons for my test cases, I would like to be able to simply save a few arguments common across all my Junit tests, right click on a specific test, then run that single run config. IE **I would like a single debug configuration that can take as an argument the current selected test case** instead of requiring me to manually specify it every time in the JUnit run configuration. My only options in the dialog appear to be either to specify a single test class or run all the tests in the project. As a result, Eclipse is littered with dozens of run configurations for all my test cases.

Instead of specifying a specific test class, I'd like it to specify a variable like ${container_loc} or ${resource_loc} for the class to run as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/369983/custom-command-for-eclipse-on-current-file). Is there a variable in Eclipse that specifies the current selected Java class that I could place in the test class field in the dialog?

A specific example where this is useful is when running the Lucene unit tests. There's lots of arguments you can specify to customize the tests, some of which like `-ea` are required. Everytime I want to test a specific test case in Lucene in Eclipse, I have to manually setup these variables in the Eclipse debug config dialog :-/.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at Parameterized Tests in JUnit?  Here  is  an  example:

```
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized.Parameters;

@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class ParamTest {
    @Parameters(name = "{index}: fib({0})={1}")
    public static Iterable<Object[]> data() {
        return Arrays.asList(new Object[][] { 
                 { 0, 0 }, { 1, 1 }, { 2, 1 }, { 3, 2 }, { 4, 3 }, { 5, 5 }, { 6, 8 }
           });
    }

    private int input;
    private int expected;

    public ParamTest(int input, int expected) {
        this.input = input;
        this.expected = expected;
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        Assert.assertEquals(expected, input);
    }
}
```

If you just want to run one test at a time you can use private variables as in:

```
    public class MultipleTest {
    private int x;
    private int y;

    public void test1(){
        Assert.assertEquals(x, y);
    }
    public void test2(){
        Assert.assertTrue(x  >y);
    }

    public void args1(){
        x=10; y=1;
    }
    public void args2(){
        x=1;y=1;
    }
    public void args3(){
        x=1;y=10;
    }
    @Test
    public void testArgs11(){
        args1();
        test1();
    }
    @Test
    public void testArgs21(){
        args2();
        test1();
    }
    @Test
    public void testArgs31(){
        args3();
        test1();
    }
    @Test
    public void testArgs12(){
        args1();
        test2();
    }
    @Test
    public void testArgs22(){
        args2();
        test2();
    }
    @Test
    public void testArgs32(){
        args3();
        test2();
    }
}
```