# Custom command for Eclipse on current buffer

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-luna

My question is related to this one : [**Custom command for Eclipse on current file**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/369983/custom-command-for-eclipse-on-current-file)

but the answer there does not exactly fit what I am looking for.

I would like to run an external command (e.g : an external code formatter) on the current buffer (e.g : pipe the buffer's content to the command's standard input) and load the result back in the current buffer, with the possibility to undo (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>) the action.

I want to act on the *buffer* content, not the content of the file stored on disk.

Is there a way to do that without writing a custom Eclipse plugin ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

External commands can't access the `Document` instance which the text editors use to store the data. External commands can only access files, so you need to save the editor content, first.

That means you either need to write a plugin which allows external commands to look at editors (maybe a JSON/REST-based query service) or you need to write a new plugin which does everything.

Have a look at [Eclipse Monkey](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse_Monkey/Overview), it should be pretty simple to create a script which does what you want without starting PDE. Note that Monkey is discontinued but it still works since it depends only on a few core APIs.

Comment: Thx for the explanations on the "you can't do it" part. Eclipse Monkey does not seem to be a good git for my need, thanks for the pointer though.